# Azure Pipelines - Gulp minified css file does not appear on server

Tags: gulp, azure-pipelines

I am new to Azure pipelines and discovered a problem I could not solve. I set up successfully an Azure Pipeline and an Azure Release Pipeline which is deploying my webapp to a virtual machine (VM). Everything is working fine. I can push my code, the pipeline gets executed and then the Repo is deployed to the VM.

Now I'm trying to execute a gulp task in the pipeline. My gulpfile looks as follows:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
 
gulp.task('minify-css', () => {
  return gulp.src('css/main.css')
    .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
    .pipe(rename('main.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

My azure-pipelines.yml looks as follows:

```
# PHP
# Test and package your PHP project.
# Add steps that run tests, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/php

trigger:
- beta

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'

variables:
  phpVersion: 7.4

steps:
- script: |
    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phpdbg /usr/bin/phpdbg$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar$(phpVersion)
    php -version
  displayName: 'Use PHP version $(phpVersion)'
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: 'content'
- task: gulp@0
  inputs:
    gulpFile: 'content/gulpfile.js'
    targets: 'minify-css'
    gulpjs: 'content/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js'
    workingDirectory: 'content'
    enableCodeCoverage: false
```

The task is executed with no errors. But after the deployment, the minified css file does not appear on the VM.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you try to use gulp-clean-css locally to compress the css file?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, on my local machine was everything working fine. I found out, that I didn't understand the process right. So the pipeline and the release pipeline are both triggered after the git push command. Then I realised, that the output of the pipeline is not automatically transferred to the release pipeline. And I dont know yet, how I can transfer the output of the pipeline to my release pipeline (Artifact?). Can you help me there?

Comment: Regarding the build pipeline, it can automatically build and validate every pull request and commit to your Azure Repos Git repository.
For more information, please refer to the document：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#ci-triggers

Comment: For the release pipeline, it can also be triggered based on pull request and commit to your Azure Repos Git repository. In addition, it can also allow you to create a release every time a new build artifact is available.
For more information, please refer to the document：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops

Comment: How I can transfer the output of the pipeline to my release pipeline (Artifact?).

Regarding Artifact, artifacts are produced from CI systems(build pipeline). They're used by the continuous delivery release pipelines to drive automatic deployments.
For more information, please refer to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/pipelines-get-started?view=azure-devops